# Primeng p-datatable column width, max-width or min-width is not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng and angular4+. I have used primeng's p-datatable for datatable.

I have set p-column style like below,

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'300px'}"> </p-column>
```

But I want to apply max-width and min-width fixed.

Note: Below is not working

```
<p-column [style]="{'max-width':'300px'}"> </p-column>
```

Output: Column width is not set as per my style. It is automatically adjusted.

Comment: What does it not working ?

Comment: Which version of primeng are you using? Would it be possible for you to create a StackBlitz?

Comment: BTW seems u didnt close your tags

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo. I want to share that max-width and min-width not working.

Comment: I am using - "primeng": "^5.2.0",